# pandas groupby apply result same size as the original dataframe

Tags: pandas

Using `data.table` in `R` I can get group conditional sum of some column like this:

```
lirbary(data.table)

dt <- data.table(id=c("A", "A", "B"),
                 amount=c(100, 10, 1),
                 category=c("cat1", "cat2", "cat1"))

dt[, conditional_amount := sum(.SD[category == "cat1"]$amount), by=.(id)]
dt
```

result:

```
   id amount category conditional_amount
1:  A    100     cat1                100
2:  A     10     cat2                100
3:  B      1     cat1                  1
```

What is the equivalent of this in pandas? When I do this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"id": ["A", "A", "B"],
                   "amount": [100, 10, 1],
                   "category": ["cat1", "cat2", "cat1"]})

g = df.groupby(["id"]).apply(lambda x: x.query("category == 'cat1'")["amount"].sum())
```

result:

```
id
A    100
B      1
dtype: int64
```

I then need to add this back to the original DataFrame:

```
g = g.reset_index()
g.columns = ["id", "conditional_amount"]
df = df.merge(g, on="id")
df
```

result:

```
  id  amount category  conditional_amount
0  A     100     cat1                 100
1  A      10     cat2                 100
2  B       1     cat1                   1
```

Is there a more succinct way of doing that? It feels like there must be, but because it's a conditional sum I cannot use `.transform` here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mask the Series before using [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['conditional_amount'] = (df['amount']
                            .where(df['category'].eq('cat1'))
                            .groupby(df['id'])
                            .transform('sum')
                           )
```

output:

```
  id  amount category  conditional_amount
0  A     100     cat1               100.0
1  A      10     cat2               100.0
2  B       1     cat1                 1.0
```